# django_filters recursive filtering

Tags: django, django-filter

so I have a django filter that looks like this:

```
class ModelFilter(FilterSet):
    user_name = CharFilter(method="some_method")
    boss = ModelChoiceFilter(...)
```

My model looks simillar to this:

```
class Employee(Model):
username = Charfield(...)
boss = ForeignKey("self", ''')
```

So an employee can be the boss of another employee. Now, this filter will return the correct queryset based on what values the user is searching for. Let's say we have three objects:

```
O1= Employee(usename="u1", boss=None)
O2= Employee(usename="u2", boss=O1)
O3= Employee(usename="u3", boss=O2)
```

If I apply the above mentioned filter on this data, and search for boss=O1 I will get the Object O2 as a result. I want to add a new boolean field in the filter, let's say "with_subordinates", that will return the whole "tree" relationship if it is true. So for instance if I would search for: boss=O1, with_subordinates=True, the resulte should be O2 and O3. Basically, with this new option, the filter should recursively show the employees, of previous employees and so forth.

Is there a way to achieve something like this?

Answer (score 0):

Apart from core concepts, we will do it the pythonic way. For this, we need to get the all objects and their `boss_id` from the database.

```
boss_object_ids = [1,] # this is the input boss id
have_to_wait = True

while have_to_wait:
    prev_ids = boss_object_ids
    if Employee.objects.filter(boss__in=boss_object_ids).count() > 0:
    
        boss_ids_list = Employee.objects.filter(boss__in=boss_object_ids).values_list('id', flat=True)
        boss_object_ids.extend(boss_ids_list)
        boss_object_ids = list(set(boss_object_ids))
        if set(boss_object_ids) == set(prev_ids):
            have_to_wait = False
all_subordinates = Employee.objects.filter(boss__in=boss_object_ids)
```

Explanation:

- At first time we pass input boss_id = [1,] or some integer.
- The second time it will loop and find 2,3,4,5 are the ids, hence the list will be [1,2,3,4,5].
- The third time it will get 2,3,4,1,6 ids, hence the list will be [1,2,3,4,5,6].
- Like wise it will filter until it gets the same list again.
- That means, in this example, it will check if there is no extra number other than [1,2,3,4,5,6].
- At last, we can filter using the `boss_object_ids` list. This is the desired all subordinates `id`'s list.